# Oily foods on Hanukkah (specifically olive oil?)

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, chanuka, eating, oil

I have heard that there is a custom to eat oily foods on Chanukah.
What is the source for this?
Is there any source that the oily foods eaten on Hanukah need to be **specifically** oily from **olive oil**?

Comment: No source, but I've always heard it's connected to the miracle of the Menorah, which was that olive oil burned for 8 days straight.

Comment: I have not seen the olive oil - food connection mentioned anywhere at all. IMO, frying latkes in olive oil gives it a "heavy" taste, which obscures the potatoes, onions and other spices, anyway. Also, I think olive oil takes much longer to heat than canola or veg. oil does. Impractical when you're frying a lot in a hurry.

Comment: @DanF who said anything about hurrying? You're preparing to engage in a mitzvah, why would you be rushing? :)

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Oh my.... You never heard of the principle, *zerizim makdimim lemitzvot*? That's enough of a reason to hurry.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like the contemporary commentators provide sources for the custom as Rav Mordechai Becher [writes](http://ohr.edu/1304) "Food fried in oil is also eaten to commemorate the miracle of the Menorah" and is echoed by Rav Y. Dov Krakowski at the [OU](https://www.ou.org/holidays/chanukah/hilchos-uminhagei-chanuka/) saying,

> There is a minhag to eat fried foods to commemorate the Miracle of the
>   Oil. Such foods are likewise being used as a tool to commemorate the
>   miracles of Chanukah thus integrating them into the Mitzvah of
>   praising Hashem.

Although the custom to fry in oil doesn't appear to be particularly only olive oil, Rav Yehuda Prero has an [insightful](http://torah.org/learning/yomtov-chanukah-5756-vol2no22/) article describing the reason for commemorating the miracle with olive oil. Aside from the longer version you can see there, he quotes the

> Aruch HaShulchan (O.C. 673:1) it is preferable to use olive oil
>   when lighting the Menorah because it is easily drawn into the wick,
>   its light burns clearly, and the miracle of Chanukah happened with
>   olive oil.

Rabbi Dovid Orlofsky offered a novel answer as to why we eat foods fried in oil on Chanuka: We counter the Greek culture which focused on [deifying](http://rabbipinchoslipschutz.blogspot.com/2009/12/bayomim-haheim-bazeman-hazeh.html) the human body by eating fried foods that shows our lack of focus on beautifying the body.

Comment: Your argument from silence is very uncompelling...